# How can I extract the value of an object from an array of objects array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections

I have an array of objects that looks like this structure below and I would like to use javascript or jquery to extract the email which is in the serviceProviderContact field e.g mike@comapny .co.za. At the moment I am using the providerName field to populate a dropdownlist but I would also like to extract the email as well.

```
providers: Array(4)
0: {providerId: 1, countryId: 1, providerName: "Vodacom", serviceProviderContact: "support@company.co.za"}
1: {providerId: 2, countryId: 1, providerName: "MTN", serviceProviderContact: "john@company.co.za"}
2: {providerId: 3, countryId: 1, providerName: "Cell C", serviceProviderContact: "mike@company.co.za"}
3: {providerId: 4, countryId: 1, providerName: "Telkom Mobile", serviceProviderContact: "Aplh@company.co.za"}
```

Comment: So you know how to grab `providerName` but you're asking how to grab `serviceProviderContact`? Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what exactly the problem is?

Comment: It looks like you want to get the array index of the selected dropdown option. A `<select>` element has a property called `.selectedIndex` that contains exactly that.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mv45o79q/

Comment: You can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to print the email id. You have to put `,` after every object to make it a valid object. `Object.values` is used to extract all the values present in the object in an array

```js
var providers = [{
    0: {
      providerId: 1,
      countryId: 1,
      providerName: "Vodacom",
      serviceProviderContact: "support@company.co.za"
    },
    1: {
      providerId: 2,
      countryId: 1,
      providerName: "MTN",
      serviceProviderContact: "john@company.co.za"
    },
    2: {
      providerId: 3,
      countryId: 1,
      providerName: "Cell C",
      serviceProviderContact: "mike@company.co.za"
    },
    3: {
      providerId: 4,
      countryId: 1,
      providerName: "Telkom Mobile",
      serviceProviderContact: "Aplh@company.co.za"
    }
  }]
  
  window.onload=function()
  {
      var k;
      var v;
  Object.values(providers[0]).forEach(e=>{
  k=document.createElement('option');
  v=document.createTextNode(e.providerName);
  k.appendChild(v)
  document.getElementById('a').appendChild(k)})
  }
  
  
  function a(name)
  {
  var x=Object.values(providers[0]).filter((e) => e.providerName==name)
  alert(x[0].serviceProviderContact)
  }
```

```html
<select id="a" onchange='a(this.value)'>
</select>
```

Comment: OP is showing console output, not source code. Anyway, turns out this doesn't answer the actual question. OP isn't just looking for `.map()` (see their comment below other answer)

Comment: Right, but OP is populating a dropdown (I assume `<select>`) and wants to display the email based on the user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `map` like so:

```
var emails = providers.map(e => e.serviceProviderContact);
```

Demonstration:

```js
 

var providers = [{providerId: 1, countryId: 1, providerName: "Vodacom", serviceProviderContact: "support@company.co.za"},
{providerId: 2, countryId: 1, providerName: "MTN", serviceProviderContact: "john@company.co.za"}
{providerId: 3, countryId: 1, providerName: "Cell C", serviceProviderContact: "mike@company.co.za"},
{providerId: 4, countryId: 1, providerName: "Telkom Mobile", serviceProviderContact: "Aplh@company.co.za"}];

var emails = providers.map(e => e.serviceProviderContact);

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: when the provider name is selected I would like to get the associated email and just put an alertbox  to display the email

Comment: @FlyBYNight That is extremely pertinent information that you should add to your question. Ideally in the form of a stack snippet that shows your own attempt at solving this.